# Delete row from database with Java, Hibernate and servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

In my web application I am trying to delete a row in my database but it doesn't seem to work and I have tried to figure out why but I can't. Here is my dao class:

```
public class userDao  {

private SessionFactory factory, session;

public userDao(SessionFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
}

public void delete(long id){
    Session session1 = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<User> u = null;
    try {
        tx = session1.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session1.createQuery("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        System.out.println("aaaaa" + id);
        u = query.list();
        session1.delete(u.get(0));
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }

    } finally {
        session1.close();
    }

}
}
```

And in my servlet i have:

```
public class DeleteServlet extends HttpServlet{
userDao u = new userDao(new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory());
User a = new User();
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    System.out.println("asa");
    response.sendRedirect("/A1.2/home.jsp");
}


@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    String s = request.getParameter("id");
    long id = Long.parseLong(s);
    u.delete(id);

    response.sendRedirect("/A1.2/home.jsp");
}
}
```

I think the problem is in the dao because I tried to get a user from the database and I got the null pointer exception.

Warnings I get:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: is there an error message or a full stacktrace? If it has, please include it in the question.

Comment: No error message, but some warnings .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HQL, you should use the class name instead of the table name, the class properties instead of the table columns. is `user_table` the name of your class? is `id` a class property or a name of column?

Comment: user_tabl is the table and id is the column, I have User.java as the class but the proprety id has the same name as the column.

Comment: So you should `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = :id`. Before that you should do the mapping with User class and the user_table. Another thing, why you get the user and than delete it? why don't you use the delete query directly `delete from User where id =:id`?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work and I don't understand why